# MyBatis foreach: there is no getter for property error

Tags: spring, mybatis

I'm getting 'there is no getter for property' error while executing foreach loop in mybatis. From the form I am gettin an array of strings (hashtag). In my PostInfoVO, I have a list of string like this:

```
private List<String> hashtags;
```

and its getters and setters like this:

```
public List<String> getHashtags() {
    return hashtags;
}
public void setHashtags(List<String> hashtags) {
    if (this.items == null)
        this.items = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

I checked that the list of hashtags is passing data to cotroller by logging postvo.getHashtags().toString().

In my MyBatis file, I have the following foreach loop which is returning 'there is no getter for property hashtag in PostInfoVO.

```
<![CDATA[
  BEGIN
  <foreach collection="hashtags" item="hashtag" separator=",">
  INSERT INTO TBL_HASHTAG_INFO(post_id, hashtag)
  VALUES
  ((SELECT post_id FROM TBL_POST_INFO ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 1), #{hashtag})
  </foreach>;
  ]]>
  END;
```

List of things I tried:

- Removing Begin and end
- Taking Insert statement out of foreach loop
- Open="(", Close=")"

Any advice would be appreciated! Thank you so much.

Comment: A few advices: 1) the question should include version info (DB, driver, MyBatis) 2) tags inside CDATA is treated as plain text, so the `<foreach />` will have no effect 3) `separator=","` does not seem right 4) enable logging so that you can check the SQL actually executed 5) not many databases/drivers support multiple statements. I recommend writing a loop in Java code. If there are many items, consider using batch executor.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code : your field name is hashtags but you used this.items in setter method and with this setter method you implemented the argument of setter method never assigns to the hashtags(field) ,Edit it as below :

```
public void setHashtags(List<String> hashtags) {
    this.hashtags = hashtags;
}
```

Comment: Oops sorry! I was frustrated and that was one of the thing i was trying.. that is my original code